# Func list for storing function pointer and parameter value

Tags: c#, func

I want to store a list of functions with their parameter value and later when I am done adding function to the list. I want to execute all in the order I have added.

For example, I want to use func instead of action and don't want to create anonymous functions while calling parametered function:

Dynamic function list class to hold a function list and execute it later.

```
class DynamicFunctionList
{
    public List<Action> DynamicList = new List<Action>();
    public void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var obj in DynamicList)
        {
           obj();
        }
    }

}
```

some class with functions

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void PrintHello()
    {
       Console.Write("Hello");

    }

    public void PrintBye()
    {
        Console.Write("Print Bye");
    }

    public int GetPrinterValue()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
}
```

And this is how you will use it

```
public static void MainClass()
    {
        var first = 0;
        var second = 0;
        var dfList = new DynamicFunctionList();
        var sClass = new SomeClass();
        dfList.DynamicList.Add(() => first = sClass.GetPrinterValue()); // problem line
        dfList.DynamicList.Add(sClass.PrintBye);
        dfList.DynamicList.Add(sClass.PrintHello);
        dfList.DynamicList.Add(() => second = sClass.Add(2, 3)); // problem
        dfList.Execute();
    }
```

Comment: Would be nice if instead of "problem" you add exact  error message you are getting. Or what exactly "problem" is.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code works. Whether it works as intended is not known to me, because you have not been clear on what the problem is and what you expect to have this code achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . there wont be error message code execute perfectly. my question is can i use func instead of action and if yes then how. because action dose not return values. so to store function with parameter and return value, I have to create another anonymous function to wrap it and then add it to list. do you think it make some sense or i should use just like this

Answer (score -1):

I do something like that:

```
    public void main()
    {
        List<MethodInvoker> methods = new List<MethodInvoker>();
        methods.Add(new MethodInvoker(SomeMethod));

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            method.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //... do something
    }
```

EDIT 1:

You can use MethodBase.Invoke from System.Reflection namespace (more infos: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can do something like that:

```
public class DynamicMethod
{        
     public string ClassName { get; set; }

     public string MethodName { get; set; }

     public object[] Parameters { get; set; }

     public static object InvokeMethod(DynamicMethod methodInfo)
     {
         var magicType = Type.GetType(methodInfo.ClassName);
         var magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
         var magicInstance = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[] {});

         var magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod(methodInfo.MethodName);
         return magicMethod.Invoke(magicInstance, methodInfo.Parameters);
     }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void main()
    {
        var d1 = new DynamicMethod
        {
            ClassName = "SomeClass",
            MethodName = "Add",
            Parameters = new object[] { 1, 2 }
        };

        var returnedValue = DynamicMethod.InvokeMethod(d1);   
        Console.WriteLine(returnedValue.ToString());
    }
```

Also you can add more information to this class, like some way to store the returned type to do the properly cast.

Comment: MethodInvoker is same as action,which is  public delegate void x(). I want to return value from the function and use it.

Comment: I edited the code and added example to use MethodBase.Invoke from System.Reflection namespace, take a look and tell me if that solves your problem.